# Laziest Checkmate

Tags: no-computers, optimization, chess

Consider a game of chess where White delivers checkmate in their $X^{th}$ move. For all the pieces that remain on the board at the end of the game, consider their [Manhattan Distances](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Manhattan-Distance) from their initial positions and take the sum. Let's say this value is $Y$.

What is the minimum possible value of $X+Y$? How many different sequences of moves can achieve this value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the rules clarified by OP I see at least 80 variations achieving a score of

> 5

Main branches:

> 1.a4/c4 b5 2.ab/cb a6/a5/c6/c5 3.ba/bc Bb7 4.ab/cb Qc8 5.bcR#/bcQ#

For a subtotal of 16 variations.

And the branch found by @Sneftel:

> 1.d4 c5 2.dc d6/d5 3.cd X 4.de Y 5.edQ# where X can be any one of 14 "time wasting moves" taken back by Y in the next move (28 variations total)
>  1.d4 e5 2.de d6/d5 3.ed X 4.dc Y 5.cdQ# where X can be any one of 18 time wasting moves (36 variations total)

For a subtotal of 64 variations.

Aside:

There is also the almost solution:

> 1.f4/h4 g5 2.fg/hg Nf6/h6 3.gf/gh Bg7 4.fg/hg and now, unfortunately, black has to move and spoil it otherwise 5.ghR#/ghQ# would also achieve 5.

Comment: Nice. Seems I highly underestimated the variety of solutions that would work out. +1

Answer (score 5):

Here's a score of 5.

> 1. d4 e5
>  2. dxe5 d6
>  3. exd6 Qe7
>  4. dxc7 Qd8
>  5. cxd8=Q#

The trick is,

> under the standard rules, promotion of a pawn results in the pawn being removed from the board and a new piece being placed in that location, rather than the pawn "becoming" the new piece (FIDE 3.7e). So the promoted queen is in its initial position, and thus Y=0.

> Black has several options to burn tempo on turns 3 and 4. There's probably a couple of other lines that could clear the necessary black material. So I suspect there's quite a few tied sequences, taking this tack.

Comment: Would be a bit hard on tournament hosts asking them to provide actual shape shifting pawns.

Comment: @loopywalt Tell me you don't want to own a pawn with a clever system of gears to unfold into a queen.

Comment: Isn't the new queen 7 squares away from its origin?

Comment: @JLee No, see the second bit.

Comment: @ManishKundu If we accept this interpretation of the rules then there are at least 3 different first moves for white.

Comment: @ManishKundu I've written it down as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I get 10 from

> 1 e3 e5 2 Qh5 Ke7 3 Qxe5#. $X=3, Y=1+5+1=7; X+Y=10$.

Comment: Can you prove that this is minimal, and also whether there are any other ways to get the same value or not?

Comment: Variation with the same score: 1. d3 e5 2. d4 exd4 3. Qxd4 Ke7 4. Qe5#